# Stop PostgreSQL instance by port number

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to stop postgres instance just by the port number?
I have a pgsql running on port 5433 and when I try to run:

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/pgsql/new_cluster/data stop
```

This will work when I specify the -D, but let's say I don't know where the $PGDATA is and all I know is the port number this instance running on, is it possible to stop it?

```
/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_ctl -p 5433 stop
```

running this command result in:

```
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
```

but when I try to enter this instance by psql -p 5433 I still can get in.
*I know it might be possible doing this with systemctl but I need doing this without root permissions.

I try to do this because: I made a pg_basebackup and I want to stop the *real* database and run the one I just created by the pg_basebackup on the same port. just to verify that the backup is ok.

Comment: Hint: `netstat` + `grep` + `ps -eo args`

Comment: Can you log in as the superuser? Then you could run `psql -p 5433 -U postgres -c 'show data_directory' ` before you take the backup and save that results somewhere.

Comment: No I cannot log into super user. And I can't seem to find the command pg_lsclusters (not in /usr/pgsql-10/bin/...)

Answer (score 0):

`-p` is not the port number in `pg_ctl`. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html) says:

> `-p path`
>
> Specifies the location of the `postgres` executable. By default the `postgres` executable is taken from the same directory as `pg_ctl`, or failing that, the hard-wired installation directory. It is not necessary to use this option unless you are doing something unusual and get errors that the `postgres` executable was not found.

So that does nothing for `pg_ctl stop`, since that finds the process ID from `postmaster.pid`.  You stopped the cluster that the environment variable `PGDATA` pointed to.

If you want to stop PostgreSQL by port number, connect as superuser (or a member of the `pg_read_all_settings` role) and run

```
SHOW config_file;
```

Then strip `postgresql.conf` from the output, and you have the argument to use with `-D`. That can easily be scripted.

Comment: And if I don't have superuser permissions... is it still possible to stop PostgreSQL just by port number? or to be able to find the $PGDATA by port and then use pg_ctl?

Comment: It is enough if the user is a member of `pg_read_all_settings`. Otherwise, you have no way to find out the data directory. But I don't understand: if you cannot be superuser, you also have no privilege to stop the server.

Comment: I can connect as postgres, but what's the command to find the path for $PGDATA?

Comment: I wrote that in my answer: `SHOW config_file;`, then strip the file name.